# Continue working on SSH session spawned on a previous proc

Tags: bash, function, tcl, expect

I wrote my first Expect script without using functions, its task is to connect to a remote host via SSH, then from the remote host start a TFTP copy.

I want to offer the user the option to copy another file, then I thought I would need to change my Expect code from a single sequence of lines and split it into functions.

First function would be to spawn SSH:

```
proc Connect {sshOptions userName switchIP userPassword aclFile} {

    spawn -noecho ssh "$sshOptions" $userName@$switchIP
    log_user 0
    expect {
            timeout exit
            -exact "Password:" { send -- "$userPassword\r" }
    }

    expect "*test#"
    send_user "Connection established\n"
}
```

Second function would be to start the copy:

```
proc Copy_ACL {aclFile} {
    send_user "Copying ACL file...\n"
    send "***copy command here**"
    expect "TFTP get operation was successful"
    send_user "ACL File copied\n"
}
```

Then I call functions as follows:

```
Connect $ssh_Options $user_Name $switch_IP $user_Password $acl_File
Copy_ACL $acl_File
```

At the moment, the issue I am facing is that, it seems function "Copy_ACL" does not know anything about the SSH session spawned by the previous function Connect. The copy command is sent to stdout although "log_user" has been set to 0.

What am I missing?

Also, is there another book about Expect besides "Exploring Expect"?

Comment: You can go [here](http://expect.sourceforge.net) to find some other guides. N.B. the marker showing the archaic examples and concentrate on what is above that marker. I don't know of any other books than the O'Reilly one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some success modifying existing code to use the same Expect session in two procs.  All that seemed to be necessary was to make `expect_out` and `spawn_id` global variables so they could be shared between the procs.  Of course, this means that only one Expect session can run at once, but that isn't likely to be a problem.

Comment: At the beginning of the script, out of the functions I declared a variable (ssh_Id) to hold the value of spawn_id when SSH was "triggered".

Within the functions I wrote "global ssh_id", and things seem to be working.

Is this approach right, is there a better way to tackle this? Thanks!

Comment: I was modifying existing code in our company's code base, so I can't directly share.  What you're doing sounds like what I did; it worked correctly for the refactoring I was doing, so I didn't have to go further, and really don't have any more depth of knowledge. Good luck!

Comment: you can always pass the `spawn_id` to expect with the `-i` parameter to expect functions. I suggest you add `return $spawn_id` to the `Connect` proc, and pass the id you get from it to `Copy_ACL`.